# How to write a test case method using Robotium in Android

Tags: android, junit4, robotium

I am writing a test case class for one of the activity in my application.

That Activity class contains license checking for the application in android market and also displays the splash screen for 3 seconds. Here I would like to test that activity is displaying the splash screen and checking the license using Robotium instrumentation in Android.

So please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To test that your splash screen is shown, you can try this, if you have set up robotium in your setup method, and named it solo:

```
public void testSplash() {
  assertNotNull(solo.getCurrentActivity().findViewById( "the id of the splash" ));
}

public void testLicense() {
  String licence = "my licence";
  assertEquals(licence, (MyActivity) solo.getCurrentActivity().getLicence());
}
```